# ASP.NET CORE 2.1 External Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

Am new to external logins in coding, so have started to get my head around the concepts but am still running into some issues. 
Effectively there are 2 sites, both hosted on the same server, and as I load one up (Lets call it MySite), it should redirect to the second Site (Lets call it LogOn), where a user can logon using their credentials. LogOn then redirects back to MySite, with the credentials which can be used to see if they have the credentials to view this site, and shown messages or data dependent on their permissions

However right now, I can get it to redirect to LogOn. I've been experimenting getting it to redirect to Microsoft login and Google also, which redirects fine, but when I set up a WsFederation and add it to my authentication services I'm not quite sure what information to put in the Wtrealm section and metadataaddress  options. Hopefully I have given enough information for someone to understand where I'm running into issues.

My code is shown below

```
            services.AddAuthentication("MyCookieAuthenticationScheme")

            .AddWsFederation("TestWs", WsOptions =>
            {
                 WsOptions.Wtrealm = "http://SiteOnServer??";
                 WsOptions.MetadataAddress = "???";
                 WsOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, just couldn't find a great deal of documentation taking you through the process.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this link contain the kink of documentation you were hoping for? There are examples and explanations here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#add-ws-federation-as-an-external-login-provider-for-aspnet-core-identity

Comment: @M.Francis I saw those links when I was testing with Google and facebook redirects, but Im still confused as to where I'm supposed to be getting the metadataddress from? I think I gather the Wtrealm is the site address (so local host whilst debugging). Sorry if I'm being painfully stupid, just very new to this aspect.

Comment: Is it not in that link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation/_static/aadfederationmetadatadocument.png?view=aspnetcore-2.1)?